# Post request in python3 with GraphQL Body

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, graphql, http-post

I'm trying to call Product Hunt V2 GraphQL APIs, 
when I do a POST request using Python "requests" library I get the following error

```
{'error': 'Bad Request', 'status': 400}
```

I tried the same request in Postman using the GraphQL body type and I successfully get a 200 status code, so I believe the problem is in the way I pass GraphQL code in my request body. Here the code I use:

```
import requests, json

url = "https://api.producthunt.com/v2/api/graphql" 

payload = {
  "query": "query { posts(first: 1) { edges { node { id, name } } } }"
}

header = {
"Accept": "application/json",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Authorization": "Bearer MYTOKEN",
"Host": "https://api.producthunt.com/v2/api/graphql"
} 


response_decoded_json = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=payload)
response_json
```

Looking at references I tried encoding the payload in Json using "json.dumps" but I always get the same 400 status code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, apparently I was using the json.dumps incorrectly.

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headerz, data=json.dumps(queryz))
```